# Jsoup baseUri gone after select

Tags: jsoup

I just discovered that setting the baseUri is necessary for each Element you get by doing a select. It would be a lot better if the baseUri of the Document is applied to each Element.

```
Document d = Jsoup.parse(myString);
doc.setBaseUri("http://www.google.de");
```

If I execute

```
Element e = d.select(....).get(0);
```

The baseUri of `e` is empty.

Is this a bug or is it intended?

Answer (score 4):

The base URI is specific to each element, as there are cases in HTML where the base URI can change throughout the parse. Currently, setting it on the document after the parse does not bubble it down to child nodes.

Just [specify](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) it when you parse the HTML string, e.g.:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myString, "http://www.google.de");
```

If you fetch the HTML from a URL and parse that (with [Jsoup.connect](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29)), the base URI is automatically set.

Comment: Afaik you set the baseURI only within the head element (<base>). I'm not fetching HTML from a URL. So setting the baseURI of the document is pretty much useless since you normally do a select after that.
Please see this as a feature request now :)

Comment: If you include it in the Jsoup.parse(url, baseUri) method like I suggest, it is used as the default and will flow to every element, unless the document overrides it.